# Getting "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child when rendering object values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render values from data object in an array but I have got these error messages

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {id, course_code, course_name, slug, course_fee, duration, start_date,
> end_date,}

I don't really know where am getting it wrong.
Here is the API object response.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Course Retrieved Successfully.",
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "course_code": "null",
    "course_name": "Greatness",
    "slug": "greatness",
    "course_fee": 10,
    "duration": "10hours",
    "start_date": "2000-09-08",
    "end_date": "2000-09-08",
  }
}
```

My code below

```
const [coursedetails, setCourseDetails] = useState([])
const [status,setStatus] = useState('init');

const init =()=>{
  setStatus('loading')

  return axios.get('http://example.com/api/courses').then(response => {
      setCourseDetails(response.data);
      setStatus('success')
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log('error',error)
      setStatus('error')
    })
}

useEffect(()=>{
  init()
},[])


return(
  <div>

  {coursedetails.data && coursedetails.data.course_name ? coursedetails.data : ''}
  <div>
)
```

Comment: Well the error message is pretty self-explanatory. You're rendering `coursedetails.data`. Based on your API response, that value is an object. And as the error says, you can't render objects directly.

Comment: Please, how do I get this right, cos I want to display each properties in the object

Comment: Well *how* do you want to display? If you just want to print them off then instead of `coursedetails.data` you can just do something like: `Object.keys(coursedetails.data).map(key => <div><b>{key}:</b> {coursedetails.data[key]}</div>)`, this loops over the keys of the object, and prints out both the key and the corresponding value

Answer (score 0):

Your closing tag is incorrect. It should be `</div>` instead of `<div>`

```
<div>

{coursedetails.data && coursedetails.data.course_name ? coursedetails.data : ''}
</div>
```